# Tapestry5 using services inside extended classes.

Tags: java, tapestry

I'm a tapestry5 user with a question about the use of services inside extended classes. Lets say I have the following class structure,

BaseClass

```
public class BaseClassImpl extends ExtendedOneClass implements BaseClass {

   @Inject
   private ServiceOne serviceOne;
}
```

ExtendedOneClass

```
public class ExtendedOneClass extends ExtendedTwoClass {

   @Inject
   private ServiceTwo serviceTwo;
}
```

ExtendedTwoClass

```
public class ExtendedTwoClas {

   @Inject
   private ServiceThree serviceThree;
}
```

What would I need to do to to be able to use services inside the extended class?

I setup my AppModule like so

```
public static void bind(ServiceBinder binder) {
    binder.bind(BaseClass.class, BaseClassImpl.class);
    binder.bind(ExtendedOneClass.class);
    binder.bind(ExtendedTwoClass.class);
}
```

But I can't seem to get the services to work inside the extended class. I'm assuming this is because the extended class hasn't been instantiated with tapestry's @Inject. So the question is how do you accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor injection and pass the services to the parent constructor:

```
public class BaseClassImpl extends ExtendedOneClass implements BaseClass
{
   private HibernateSessionSource hibernateSessionSource;

   public BaseClassImpl(SystemEnvironment systemEnvironment, LinkSource linkSource, 
                        HibernateSessionSource hibernateSessionSource)
   {
       super(systemEnvironment, linkSource);
   }
}
```

Anyway your setup will not work, you need to add service ids in this setup, because otherwise you'll have multiple services implementing the same interface. This should help:

```
binder.bind(ExtendedOneClass.class).withId("ext1");
```

In combination with this:

```
@InjectService("ext1")
private ExtendedOneClass extendedOneClass;
```